# Avd not launching on the eclipse

Tags: android

I have created a avd  for nokia x  on my eclipse. And is successfully created but when I start it , it does not starts up. it shows that its launching with a progress bar but it does not launches and does not gives any error also. I have installed all required plugins

Answer (score 0):

Please delete your current AVD and restart the Eclipse . Sometimes, some abnormal malfunctions may happen unknowingly...

I'm attaching a screen shot for you to create an AVD with all necessary details., please follow and create the new AVD. That should help you to proceed further.

on a sidenote - I believe you system has a minimum of 4GB RAM in order to see the AVD coming up faster. If the RAM is less, then it may take good amount of time to come up and show on the screen.

I believe you are also aware of the HAXM and Intel Virtualization technique to make the Emulator run faster. If any doubts...follow this link as well posted by me - [HAXM guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24087146/haxm-gone-after-latest-sdk-update/24087439#24087439)

[image]